# Specify time of events sent with AppInsights?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

Is there a way to set the time of events manually sent in App Insights? I'm using the ApplicationInsights package from @microsoft/applicationinsights-web in a react app. As an example, I want to execute something like this at 6:00pm ETC Apr 26, 2022:

```js
    appInsights.trackEvent({
        name: "my cool event",
        properties: {
            greeting: "hello world"
        },
    });
```

But have it logged in my azure portal as happening at 5:00pm ETC Apr 26, 2022. I figured there would be a `time` property or something I could set on the parameter object, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, We have `trackDependencyData`, which is the `IDependencyTelemetry` interface, which has `startTime` as a parameter to know the `telemetry event start time`.

Sample code:-

```
var success = false;
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
try
{
    success = dependency.Call();
}
finally
{
    var elapsed = new Date() - startTime;
    telemetry.trackDependency({
        dependencyTypeName: "myDependency",
        name: "myCall",
        duration: elapsed,
        success: success
    });
}
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT|** [***trackDependency***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackdependency) , [***API SUMMARY***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#api-summary)
- **SO THREAD** | [***Azure Application Insight JavaScript SDK trackEvent Timestamp***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69636150/azure-application-insight-javascript-sdk-trackevent-timestamp)

Comment: Is this method available in appinsights react sdk as well? I tried this --> `const ai = useAppInsightsContext(); ai.trackDependencyData({/* props */})`, but its not working.